# Get all documents from firestore which contains a particular value in its subcollection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection say users and it has a subcollection vehicles(type,vehicleNo etc). I want to get all  users who have a two-wheeler(type==two-wheeler). Is this possible with a firestore single query? How can I get those documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  A query can consider only the documents within a single collection at a time.  It can't reach into subcollections.  What you will have to do is either copy the required data from the subcollection in the main collection that you need for the query, or compose a whole new collection that you can query.  Duplicating data like this is common for NoSQL type databases like Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just duplicated it now.